# AQGridView - How to detect a touch instead of a selection?

Tags: iphone, selection, tap, aqgridview

I've incorporated the really awesome AQGridView into my project but am having a small problem,

The only delegate method i find is
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

Which only detects a select, meaning - if i select a cell and then want to "deselect" a cell i just clicked, i would have to click on another cell, or click twice on that cell to perform a deselection.

If i could just detect a touch instead i could just trigger the selection, but since it saves the touch status, the problem i just described occurs.

I would love to hear from you guys if you have any info on this or suggestions :)

Kind regards,
Shai.

Comment: You could tell the grid view to deselect the item when it is selected. In `- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;` Call `deselectItemAtIndex:index animated:animated`

Comment: So simple! thank you ! :) You should write it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could tell the grid view to deselect the item when it is selected. In

```
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Call

```
[gridView deselectItemAtIndex:index animated:animated];
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple , feel kinda stupid i didn't think of it myself :)